# Angular MSAL get profile pictures

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.http.get<User[]>("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users")
      .subscribe(users => {
        console.log(users);
        this.users = users;
    });
  }
```

I have the above and the result bound to a dropdown:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="users" optionLabel="displayName" [filter]="true">
    <ng-template let-user pTemplate="item">
        <div>
            <div>{{ user.displayName }}</div>
            <div>({{ user.mail }})</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

I'm struggling to get the profile photo using MSAL and displaying it for each user:

- It needs to also handle those without profile photos.

I believe I need to loop over every user.id and then get the photo? But whenever I try to do it I get 404 not found (even for users who have a profile photo):

**What I tried:**

Adding the getPhoto method:

```
  getUserPhoto(userId: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${userId}/photo/$value`;
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```

Adding to the dropdown:

```
<div *ngIf="getUserPhoto(user.id)"><img [src]="getUserPhoto(user.id)" alt="not found"></div>
```

It shows not found (alt text) and in console I have the 404 not found error